# Java arguments passing and references

Tags: java, reference

I can't actually see *how* Java manages the object's references passing. I expose this situation to tell my doubt.

```
public class Clase {


    public void metodo (int i, Integer objeto) {

        i++;
        objeto++;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int         i = 5;
        Integer     object = new Integer(8);

        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(object);

        new Clase().metodo(i, object);

        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(object);


    }

}
```

All I'm getting printed is:

> **`5`**
>   **`8`**
>   **`5`**
>   **`8`**

So, as long as I'm receiving in the method a primitive and an object, shouldn't the object be changing from the method too?

Answer (score 3):

Example object you used (`Integer`) is immutable object (which is same like `String`). Try same example with non immutable objects, you will get answer as you expected.

Comment: So Integer just like a String, is a final class, right?

Comment: Here is code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java